# Pandas Rolling Regression: y_fitted vs y_predict difference

Tags: python, pandas, regression

First time posting, please excuse any mistakes I made.

I just ran a rolling regression with the model: Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X3 in pandas.
I know that model.y_fitted returns the fitted values, which is just X * beta.

But what is y_predict? It returned slightly different values compared to y_fitted. I am very curious what type of calculation it is doing.

Sample Code:

```
model = pd.ols(y=Y, x=X, intercept=False, window=500)
model.y_fitted
model.y_predict
```

The above returns slightly different values.
[Click here screenshot of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcqJa.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9966145/5276797), "pandas y_predict and y_fitted should give you the same value". Maybe follow the link to find out more...

Comment: See this thread which is asking the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943848/forecasting-using-pandas-ols